# Redux and ContextProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context, redux-toolkit

I am really new to React and Redux I was following a tutorial in which you create a app that have a state Context Provider.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const StateContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  chat: false,
  cart: false,
  userProfile: false,
  notification: false,
};

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(undefined);
  const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('#03C9D7');
  const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState('Light');
  const [themeSettings, setThemeSettings] = useState(false);
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(initialState);

  const setMode = (e) => {
    setCurrentMode(e.target.value);
    localStorage.setItem('themeMode', e.target.value);
  };

  const setColor = (color) => {
    setCurrentColor(color);
    localStorage.setItem('colorMode', color);
  };

  const handleClick = (clicked) => setIsClicked({ ...initialState, [clicked]: true });

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ currentColor, currentMode, activeMenu, screenSize, setScreenSize, handleClick, isClicked, initialState, setIsClicked, setActiveMenu, setCurrentColor, setCurrentMode, setMode, setColor, themeSettings, setThemeSettings }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

with which you wrap the app.render with

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

But now I want to use Redux-toolkit to manage states that are coming from a back-end server.
I think I need to convert what is inside this ContextProvider into a reduxSlice but I have no idea how to do so and I tried using Redux by wrap my app with the redux provider like so

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
     <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
   </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

that also didn't work